# Handle message window close event

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I keep seeing different variation of the code which is supposed to register an Inspector window close event but I have no idea where to put the code. Should it be in the addin startup function (ThisAddIn_Startup), in the item click event handler or somewhere else? And how to properly unregister the handler if it's eg. registered for each mail item?

Here's some sample code I found (that I'm not sure where to put):

```
InspectorEvents_10_Event inspectorEvent = selectedItem[1].GetInspector();
inspectorEvent.Close += ItemClosed;
```

This tutorial also says there are two types of the Close even that I might need to handle
https://sites.google.com/site/xushengxiaotech/Home/http---sites-google-com-site-xushengxiaoshome-home-handling-the-close-event-correctly-using-outlook-object-model

Where do I register the handlers for those?

Answer (score 0):

You need to track Inspectors.NewInspector event (set up the event handler on startup). Then when NewInspector fires, set the event handler for the Inspector.Close event on the new inspector.

Comment: OK, I've created an event handler for NewInspector and inside added the line: `inspector.Close += OnInspectorClose;` but it underlines the inspector.Close expression and says it cannot assign to Close mecause it is a method group.

Comment: I've cast the inspector instance to an event class and it seems to work: `var inspectorEvent = inspector as InspectorEvents_10_Event;` (and then register the handler to inspectorEvent `inspectorEvent.Close += OnInspectorClose;`). But how do I unregister it correctly now?

Comment: Create a wrapper class that has Inspector as one of its members and handles Inspector.Close event. In the NewInspector event handler, create a new instance of that class and add it to a list stored on the addin class level. When the wrapper class handles Inspector.Close event, it will unregister the event handler and remove itself from the list of wrappers stored by the parent addin class.

Comment: Hmmm, ok and what event should I register to if I want to prevent the "Do you want to save changes in the message" dialog? Inspector.Close fires only after that.

Comment: You will need to either save the message yourself (MailItem.Save) or close the message before the user does using MailItem.Close(olDiscard)

Comment: I tried closing the message myself but if I do it in the NewInspector event handler it crashes Outlook (I guess inspector is not fully initialized at this point and not ready to be closed).